File Corruption Issue When Transferring from External Server to Google Cloud Storage
When attempting to transfer files from an external server to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket using the provided code snippet (code to be executed on Google Cloud Functions), the files are transferred successfully but end up being corrupt in the destination bucket. The following code illustrates the problematic scenario:
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(GCS_BUCKET)
blob = bucket.blob(gcs_full_path)
with requests.get(external_url, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if content_type:
        blob.upload_from_file(response.raw, content_type=content_type)
    else:
        blob.upload_from_file(response.raw, content_type=f"application/{file_content_type}")

Sample external_url  = https://www.mrt.tas.gov.au/mrtdoc/dominfo/download/UR1994_22/UR1994_22.pdf 
However, switching to upload_from_string() resolves the corruption issue. Here's the alternative code snippet that successfully uploads files without corruption, albeit with a less memory-efficient approach:
response = requests.get(external_url)
response.raise_for_status()
blob.upload_from_string(response.content, content_type=content_type)

However, this solution is less efficient for large files as it loads the entire file into memory before uploading. Is there an alternative approach wherein I can transfer the file content with integrity, and not loading all of it in the memory?

Do you use streaming mode also with String transfer mode?

I tried doing the stream mode with from string but it produced errors.

Have a look on the bad side of streaming mode: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming-uploads#should-you-use

@guillaumeblaquiere do you think {'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked'} could be the reason why the file is written out to be corrupted?

It depends what you mean by "corrupted". Did you compare the file checksum (or MD5)? Your corruption could also be a bad content type or bad naming. In fact, if 100% of files are corrupted, it could not be a transfer error (corruption can occur, but sometimes, not every time!)
